# get login/logout notification from active directory in c#

Tags: c#-4.0, active-directory

i am trying to do a small app that monitor the login/logout of usres in AD. currently i am monitoring the event log of the security. but i am looking for a more AD way

Comment: Are you trying to log the login / logout of users on individual machines from a central server?

Comment: i have tried the notification but failed geeting any, and i have read that it is not scalable, dirsync is only pull, i am looking for push based

Answer (score 0):

There is no mechanism in AD to provide this sort of eventing...

Comment: so event log is my only way? to connect to the event log in the AD server

Comment: Pretty much. You could configure notifications through that pipeline with WMI or something along that line...